# Get LAN IP address from USB tethering network from javascript

Tags: javascript, ip-address

I know it sound crazy but I need it.

I found code that gets the public IP address:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function getip(json){
      alert(json.ip); // alerts the ip address
    } </script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
```

But that code can't help me here. I do even know if this is possible. But I am looking for the 192.168.42.123 address. How can I found this IP from javascript ?

> $ ifconfig
>
> usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6b:fe:56:15:6b:33
>             inet addr:192.168.42.123  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::68fe:96ff:fe15:6b49/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:1802 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:2041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:1513563 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:318292 (318.2 KB)

Comment: I doubt that possible, JS doesn't have access to the hardware / file system. Would be a wee-bit of a security issue

Comment: Your WAN address is possible, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript).

Comment: this used to work:     var ip=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
    ip.getHostAddress(); still might on a custom setup with old firefox, if IP is make or break... you can probably sniff an img file from the router config from 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1, that's a fun little timing/error attack that's easy to launch from js, but won't get you the full IP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Whenever he's running your script, the user is on the public network (Internet), and therefore the IP address you'll get through javascript will always be the public one. But you may be taking the problem from the wrong side and doesn't actually need this IP address... there's nothing in it that a remote user could use...